# the usage of "in response"

Tags: phrase-usage

*My decision to resign is in response to your attacks on core values of the United States*.

Do you find the usage of in "response" in the above sentence OK? I would use these alternatives; but of course I am not a native speaker:

1. In response to your attack…, I decided to resign.
2. My decision to resign is the response to your attack.

Comment: Yes, it's completely fine, and there are 371 results that match `[be] in response to` in COCA.

Comment: It's fine. Your first alternative is ok. Second alternative, "the response" is overbroad. *My response to your attack is to resign*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: As ever, it's all about *precise* context. For example, the phrasing in #2 could be perfectly natural as a reply to *I raised some serious issues concerning your chairmanship at the board meeting last week, but apparently you haven't responded. Do you have anything to say before I table a vote of no confidence?*